# Sequence in normed vector space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

At the beginning of some proofs, there is wrtitten: Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $x_n$ be a sequence which converges to zero.

My question is why I can obtain such a sequence?
I know that if $x = inf(M)$, then from definition of infimum I can obtain a sequence $x_n$ converging to $x $.

Thank you.

Comment: $$ (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dotsc). $$

Comment: Or, more generally, take *any* sequence $(u_n)$ and set $$x_n = \frac{1}{n\|u_n\|} u_n. $$  Then $\|x_n\| = \frac{1}{n}$, and so $x_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick your favourite $x\in X$ and then define $x_n = \frac{1}{n} x$. This is a sequence converging to zero.

Comment: Thank you. So if I want $x_n$ converging to $x$, I can choose for example $x_n = \frac{n}{n+1} x$ and that is it?

Comment: Yes. Or take any sequence $y_n$ which converges to $0$ and consider $x_n:=x+y_n$.

Comment: @Cygne Yes, you can use your sequence, or you can pick the one by Berci. Or you can directly pick the sequence $x_n =x$. There is a lot of possible choices.